# How do I return to Germany with an exisiting residence permit after an internship in Japan?

Tags: visas, german-residents

I am a student of Aachen International University pursuing a Masters in Engineering but am presently doing an internship in Japan. My resident permit in Germany is valid up to 31-07-2017. I am completing my internship by the end of Jan. 2017 but my course has not been completed yet. Someone informed me that your visa in Germany gets automatically cancelled if you are out of Germany.

Will there be any problems in returning to Germany and if so what do I need to do to overcome them?